# How to implement Ranges in D

Tags: range, d

How do you implement your own range in D? I've looked everywhere but I can't find any documentation on which methods (like `popFront`, for example) need to be implemented for which kinds of ranges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be it

http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_range.html

Comment: I've already seen that link, but the problem is, it doesn't document the *requirements* for ranges; it just documents the ranges that have been already implemented, which can contain more methods than required.

Comment: My bad, you're right; I missed the documentation on `InputRange`. Thanks!

Comment: The requirements are actually found under the is...Range sections. The minimal range, isInputRange, consists of front, popFront, empty